# How to fetch data from web in iOS?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios

I want to create an application send an request like "http://www.mysiteabc.com/api.php?email=emailtologin@gmail.com&password=123321" and read data return from a web. Anybody can show me how to do this. Thanks

Comment: You should really accept some answers to your questions. If you don't, people will downvote your questions and stop answering them. To accept an answer, press the ✔ next to the question that you think helped you the most. It will reward you by giving you +2 reputation, and the author of your accepted answer with +10 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the extensive [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i), and pay particular attention to [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).